# Need Realtek ALC221VB Drivers

Tags: linux, audio, realtek, microphone

I have HP 280 G2 MT system which comes with Integrated Realtek ALC221VB with combo microphone/headphone jack

Out of box it only works for listening to audio. The combo jack doesn't work for microphone

Where do I get drivers for linux

Additional info

OS - Linux Mint 18.1
Linux Kernel - 4.4

Comment: If the sound works, then the drivers are already installed.  What are you trying with the microphone that's not working?

Answer (score 1):

The audio drivers are loaded and working properly. To make things easier, just follow what has already been exposed here by Erel Segal-Halevi:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working

1. Install `pavucontrol`: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
2. `sudo pavucontrol`
3. Go to the "Input Devices" tab & click the lock icon to unlock the channels Under "Port", select the correct microphone (front or rear)

Comment: You're probably right but I was hoping OP would make a minimal effort in clarifying what they need help with.